# Failure while dumping the provider: java.io.IOException: Timeout

Tags: python, android, kivy, adb

I'm testing a Kivy app on Android and it crashes on launch. I ran `adb bugreport` and on the bottom of the output I read

> Failure while dumping the provider: java.io.IOException: Timeout

What can I do ? If you need more details just ask.

full log can be seen here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ix3nkeuxt28h1r0/bugreport-NRD90M-2020-01-25-00-15-27.txt?dl=0

```
I/python  ( 9447): [WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <assets/sounds/music.mp3>
I/python  ( 9447): [WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <assets/sounds/r2d2_hit.mp3>
I/python  ( 9447): [WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <assets/sounds/R2D2_informs_of_force_enabled.mp3>
I/python  ( 9447): [WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <assets/sounds/lightsaber_on.mp3>
I/python  ( 9447): [WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <assets/sounds/lightsaber_off.mp3>
I/python  ( 9447):  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
I/python  ( 9447): Python for android ended.
```

Comment: Post the full log, I'm not clear if this is anything to do with the app crashing.

Comment: @inclement  The full log is long and extensive. I'm gonna upload it somewhere and provide link.

Comment: @inclement  Added log.

Comment: Can you post the logcat output rather than bugreport. Also, look for the string `python` in the logcat.

Comment: Here https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmxf4ttec2igtdr/logcat.txt?dl=0  but when I searched for "python" with CTRL+F nothing came up.

Comment: I've found only 2 clues from the logcat output:  `AppOps  : No existing app ops /data/system/appops.xml; starting empty` and `Failure preloading resources`

Comment: When debugging on another phone I discovered this:
`I/python  ( 7448): [WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <assets/sounds/` few times. SoundLoader comes with Kivy so why it can't find it ?

Comment: I don't see anything familiar in that logcat. Is it definitely from when you attempted to open the app?

Comment: Give me a sec ... will edit the post to show what I'm basing this on.

Comment: I bet the error refers to SoundLoader class that I'm using to play sounds in the app.

Comment: Feel free to have a look at the code.  https://gitlab.com/godsengineer/trackerwars/blob/master/main.py

Answer (score 0):

As turned out it's a well known fact among Kivy devs that Kivy won't load mp3 sounds in Android. Will play wavs and oggs and these formats need to be specifically included in `source.include_exts` in the `buildozer.spec` file.